# Removing .DS_Store and ._.DS_Store recursively while preserving directory modified dates

Tags: bash, last-modified

I've been doing the long slow shift from OSX to Windows (for the usual reasons), and I've gone through the laborious process of shifting over my entire documents directory, with it's many sub/sub/sub/directories, while still preserving all of the modification dates, because dates are an important part of how I organize.

My trouble, a little nit-picky I suppose, is my directories are left peppered with .DS_Store and ._.DS_Store files. I want to delete them, but if i do, it changes the modification date of the parent directory, which is ruinous.

I'm hoping to accomplish this task by running a script in each directory like such:

```
#!/bin/bash         
# get the current directory's timestamp
STR2=$(stat -c %y .)
STR=$(/usr/bin/date +%Y%m%d%H%M -d "$STR2")

# Remove the offending files
rm ./.DS_Store
rm ./._.DS_Store

# Reset the current directory's timestamp
touch -a -m -t $STR .
```

And then executing the script recursively, from the top level directory, like such:

```
find * -name '.DS_Store' -execdir /path/to/script/script.sh \;
```

This *appears* to work in a test copy of my folders, but before I unleash it on my precious documents folder, I was hoping to get some feedback/warnings on possible sinkholes in my strategy.

Thanks!

p.s. efficiency isn't really an issue here, because I'll only run it once (and it's not intensive).

Comment: I have tested it in a backup, but there are literally hundreds of directories in /my/precious, and I might not discover any mistakes for months. Hoping to know in advance if there are any obvious potholes. For example, I know the 'find' command can be tricky...

Comment: If you have a working program and looking for review, [codereview.se] is a better place for that than [so].

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you don't preserve seconds ?

Comment: I suppose that seconds don't matter that much to me. My main motivation is to be able to sort by date and have the more recent versions be on the top.

Comment: I would first create a temporary file, say, /tmp/tempxxx, by `mkdir /tmp/tempxxx` before calling `find` and within the script I'd do : `touch -r . /tmp/tempxxx; rm ./.DS_Store ./._.DS_Store; touch -r /tmp/tempxxx .`.

Comment: Are there advantages to updating the timestamp based on another file vs. just storing it it in a string? Or does it just feel cleaner to you to do it that way?

Comment: No advantages other than portability. As you'll run this script once on your local setup which has GNU stat and date, that doesn't matter at all.